# Ubuntu 18.04. 1 live usb.. Unable to use laptop keyboard and track pad..?

Tags: live-cd

I'm using asus fx504gm laptop with nvidia 1060.
I'm trying to load live usb.. The desktop gets loaded but I'm unable to use any peripherals.. Only external mouse cursor is movable and can't select anything with that too
This forces me to power off laptop forcing always! 
Please help me! Im a newbie here!

Comment: Can you access a terminal login by typing Ctrl-Alt-F1? May be a graphics driver issue. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)